# No results for a query that's supposed to show sales in August for refunded customers in July

Tags: sql, date, between

I'm using 2 tables - one of refunded ID's and one of Orders ID and I want to find the ID's that got any refund in July and spent money in August.

When I use this query I get no results:

```
Select ord.id
FROM `grouponi_groupon.tb_orders_refund` as ref, `grouponi_groupon.tb_orders_items` as ord
WHERE
ref.id = ord.id
and ref.last_update BETWEEN '2022-07-01' AND '2022-07-31'
and ord.last_update BETWEEN '2022-08-01' AND '2022-08-31'
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Would the ORDER be refunded in July and then THE SAME ORDER have spent money in August, or should that be the USER or CUSTOMER who would have an order refunded in July and then THE SAME USER/CUSTOMER spent money in August? I would expect that order numbers would not be re-used from month-to-month.

Comment: What is the type of `last_update` columns?

Answer (score 0):

I think a subquery is in order here.
First step - Find the (unique) customers that got a refund in July:

```
SELECT DISTINCT userid
FROM tb_orders_refund
WHERE last_update BETWEEN '2022-07-01' AND '2022-07-31'
```

Step 2 - Show sales in August only for customers that we retrieved in the 1st step:

```
SELECT *
FROM tb_orders_items
WHERE last_update BETWEEN '2022-08-01' AND '2022-08-31'
AND userid IN (SELECT DISTINCT userid
               FROM tb_orders_refund
               WHERE last_update BETWEEN '2022-07-01' AND '2022-07-31')
```